# NullReferenceException on (seemingly) completely initialized objects

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, graph-theory

I'm trying to load and display a GraphML document using the [Graph# library for C#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com), and am getting a `NullReferenceException` on a line that doesn't seem to make sense:

```
private void load(string fileName) {
    var graph = new CompoundGraph<object, IEdge<object>>();

    //open the file of the graph
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName);

    //create the serializer
    var serializer = new GraphMLDeserializer<object,
        IEdge<object>,
        CompoundGraph<object, IEdge<object>>>();

    //deserialize the graph
    serializer.Deserialize(reader, graph,
        id => id, (source, target, id) => new Edge<object>(source, target)
        );

    Console.WriteLine(graph);               // okay
    Console.WriteLine(graphLayout.Graph);   // okay

    this.graphLayout.Graph = graph;         // crashes
    this.graphLayout.UpdateLayout();
}
```

I've checked the object values using the debugger and everything seems to be in order.
What else could be going wrong?
Why am I getting a `NullReferenceException` on objects that have been initialized?

If you prefer to browse the entire source (or compile it yourself if you are so incline; you're more than welcome to), I have been making the project available on GitHub for some time.  I've added [a commit](https://github.com/vermiculus/ssa-tool/blob/c107cf6e026fb9e2cd245e9afd8b83fa6ea01714/SMP/Simulator.xaml.cs) that reproduces the problem.

Full stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=GraphSharp.Controls
  StackTrace:
       at GraphSharp.Controls.GraphLayout`3.Layout(Boolean continueLayout)
       at GraphSharp.Controls.GraphLayout`3.Relayout()
       at GraphSharp.Controls.GraphLayout`3.OnRelayoutInduction(Boolean tryKeepControls)
       at GraphSharp.Controls.GraphLayout`3.Graph_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
       at GraphSharp.Controls.GraphLayout`3.set_Graph(TGraph value)
       at SMP.MainWindow.load(String fileName) in t:\#_\Programming\GitHub\SMP\SMP\Simulator.xaml.cs:line 61
       at SMP.MainWindow.Load_GMX_Graph(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in t:\#_\Programming\GitHub\SMP\SMP\Simulator.xaml.cs:line 38
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at SMP.App.Main() in t:\#_\Programming\GitHub\SMP\SMP\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace on the error?

Comment: Done.  But may I ask, if you know, what is the significance of the backtick in the stack trace on some of the lines?

Comment: @SeanAllred: the backtick indicates that the class is a generic class with 3 generic parameters.

Comment: The exception is coming from code that is invoked in response to the property change. Your objects are all fine. That is, it's a bug in the library.

Comment: siride is correct in that it's occurring in the library.  However it's likely that there is a required property that you aren't setting which is why the internal call to `.Layout` is failing.  Given the name of the method, my money is that it has no idea what it's parent is - and therefore has no surface to draw itself on.  Maybe it needs to be added to the controls property of your form.

Comment: @ChrisLively: I still consider it a bug that it throws a generic NullReferenceException instead of checking for proper configuration first and throwing a more specific exception in a more appropriate location.

Comment: The library is open source though. Download the code and let the debugger break on the exception.

Comment: @siride: Oh, I completely agree with you.  It's poor exception handling in the graph code.

Comment: @ChrisLively Shouldn't the [XAML](https://github.com/vermiculus/ssa-tool/blob/c107cf6e026fb9e2cd245e9afd8b83fa6ea01714/SMP/Simulator.xaml#L24) be implicitly setting the parent container, though?  (On second thought, I suppose that's why they call it a bug.  How would I go about doing this programmatically?  [as an answer?])

Answer (score 0):

check the file Simulator.xaml.cs on line 61. Your last code is there before the exception was thrown...